# tlv and protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to attach the protobuf-c message to the Value in the TLV and send it over network. But I dont see the correct contents in the packet dump. Below is the tlv struct and .proto file.

```
struct test_tlv { 
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int len;
    unsigned int val;
};
message testproto
{
    optional uint32 type=1;
    optional string id =2;
}
```

filled the message values as `test.type= 2 and test.id="0xabcdbcda";`

I have used protobuf api to pack the test into the val and send tlv over network, but I dont see the correct values in the dumped packet. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You can use already implementation [tlv encoder project](https://github.com/VakhoQ/tlv-encoder)   in order to convert the structure to a byte array and to revert it. You can attach the result byte array to protocol buffer structure and sent it via the network. It's just option...

Answer (score 0):

As the messages are encoded in varints i was in a assumption that the values are wrong.. after decoding them the values looked right.